# I am trying to remember the name of a tool I used in college for a phonetics project

Tags: terminology

I asked a native speaker of an unfamiliar language to say, in his native language, each of about 250 words so that I could transcribe them phonetically. Theoretically,this specific list of words would elicit all of the distinct phonemes (and allophones?) in any (or many) languages. What is the name of this list of words?

Comment: Was it the Swadesh list? It's not about phonemes (after all you don't know which words will have which phonemes in an unfamiliar language) but it's commonly used for tasks like this.

Answer (score 3):

No list of words gives you all of the phonemes and allophones of all languages. There is a fair chance that some list of 1,000 words might reveal the phonemes of a language (not the allophones), but even then there isn't a universal list of words, because there are very few universal words (what it the Eskimo word for camel, or the Zulu word for polar bear?). Most instructors of field methods classes have a list of around 500 words as suggestions, usually tailored to the facts of the target language (not asking for inappropriate lexical items, not being highly Anglocentric in asking the words for "ship", "boat", "skiff", "steamer" when such distinctions don't exist in most languages.

There are a couple of named lists, the Swadesh list and the Leipzig-Jakarta list, which is used to construct statistical measures of historical separation between languages.